# Getting Alpha Numeric Strings for the name field in Subscribe Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, error-handling

So here's something that's bothering me for a while. I have a Subscribe form in my website and for few of the subscriptions that I have received, the name field is showing some alpha-numeric string instead of name of the person. Below are few of the strings that I received for the name field.

5a34f0a1d7ef3, 5a3500bce345d, 5a35534ac5108, 5a36176c98c75

For an instance if I am receiving 20 subscriptions in a day, 4 of them are like this and rest are correct. What exactly could be wrong in the form? Below is the form I'm talking about:

[Subscription Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLAMm.png)

Any help and suggestion would be GREAT!!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please elaborate your question with more information about your application like its language, the framework you use, your database etc. Anything that might be useful for people to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

They’re likely spam from bots. Either ignore them, or consider using [Google reCAPTCHA on your form](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html).